# Process suspended after start in Eclipse Debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm facing following Problem with Eclipse Debugger. I'm starting JBoss 5.1 in Debug-Mode directly from Eclipse (This process runs almost the whole day without restart) and sometimes when I want to start new Debug-Sesion with the Client Application (Swing + OSGi) or event debug some JUnit-Tests eclipse starts the process, but this new process is immediately suspended. When I change the Perspective to debug, I can see two process - JBoss is running without problems, but the new process is suspended - the Console output is clear, the process hat the Eclipse-Icon for suspended Threads. Sometimes it helps to select this process and to press the green "Resume" Button, sometimes I have to kill this process with "Terminate an Remove". When I try to run this process again I run sometimes in the same situation, sometimes runs the new process without problems.

Really strange is, when eclipse "suspended" the new Client-App-process and I kill in Debug Perpective the JBoss process, the second, suspended process runs suddenly. I think, that these two process runs in some "deadlock" situation, but I don't know how to fix this.

I don't have any Idea, what is the reason of this Problem...
My Environment: Eclipse 4.3.2, Java 1.7.0_21-64bit

Answer (score 0):

This program might help you to understand your situation:

```
class Solution {
    public static ListNode reverseKGroup(ListNode head, int k) {
        ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode(0);
        dummyHead.next = head;
        ListNode prev = dummyHead, cur = dummyHead;
        while (cur != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                if (cur == null || cur.next == null) return dummyHead.next;
                cur = cur.next;
            }
            ListNode nxt = prev.next;
            prev.next = reverse(prev.next, cur.next);
            prev = nxt;
            System.out.println(prev);
            cur = nxt;
        }
        return dummyHead.next;
    }

    private static ListNode reverse(ListNode head, ListNode tail) {
        if (head == tail || head.next == tail) return head;
        ListNode prev = head, cur = head.next;
        while (cur != tail) {
            ListNode nxt = cur.next;
            cur.next = prev;
            //System.out.println("cur.next:" + cur.next);
            prev = cur;
            //System.out.println("prev:" + prev);
            cur = nxt;
        }
        //head.next = tail;
        return prev;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode l1 = new ListNode(1);   
        l1.next = new ListNode(2);  
        l1.next.next = new ListNode(3);  
        l1.next.next.next = new ListNode(4);
        l1.next.next.next.next= new ListNode(5);

        System.out.println(reverseKGroup(l1, 3));
    }
}

public class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) { val = x; }

    public String toString(){
        String retVal = "";
        ListNode n = this;
        while(n!=null){
            retVal += n.val +" ";
            n = n.next;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

When you will start debugger and try to debug the value of prev, the process will get suspended.